# The method insert(String, Class<T>) in the type Data is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics

I want to have a function that takes in a generic type argument, but I am getting error message for using this. How do I use generic the right way in Java?

```
Plane plane = new Plane();
Car car = new Car();
data.insert("fast", car);
data.insert("super fast", plane);
...
<T> void insert(String a, Class<T> object) {
    System.out.println("Inserting " + object.getName() + a);
}
```

Comment: remove `<T>` and replace `Class<T>` with `Class<?>` you don't seem to use the generic parameter at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert function is expecting a Class object like `Plane.class`, that's why `object.getName()` is known.

I think your intention would be something like:

```
<T extends HasName> void insert(String a, T object) {
    System.out.println("Inserting " + object.getName() + a);
}
```

where HasName is an interface(could be a super class, too), with method `getName`, that is implemented(extended) by Car and Plane.
That's how to ensure that `object.getName()` can be called.